# Django "Unknown column in where clause" for exclude, but not filter

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Sale model with a foreign key to a Prints model with a foreign key to a Shirt model and finally a foreign key to a Style model. In that last model, there is a ptype field which is a foreign key to another model.

The columns all exist in the mysql tables (its been in use for a while, but I still quadruple checked).

This is the code I have:

```
sales = sales.exclude(print__shirt__style__ptype=ptype)
```

It's giving me this error:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'appname_prints.ptype_id' in 'where clause'")
```

Notice that its looking for the ptype_id field in the prints model and not in the style model. Why is it ignoring '__*shirt _*_style'?

The style model also has a brand foreign key. I've tried replacing ptype with brand just to see what would happen and it worked. This is the change:

```
sales = sales.exclude(print__shirt__style__brand=brand)
```

If I change exclude() to filter() and change nothing else, it works (except for obviously doing the opposite of what I need).

```
sales = sales.filter(print__shirt__style__ptype=ptype)
```

Just for completeness, the following also gives the same error

```
sales = sales.filter(~Q(print__shirt__style__ptype=ptype))
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/vhosts/domain.com/django/projectname/appname/admin_views.py" in popularity_report
  1032.     for s in sales:
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _result_iter
  118.                 self._fill_cache()
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fill_cache
  892.                     self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  291.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  763.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  818.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  114.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  201.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/vhosts/domain.com/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /popularity/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'appname_prints.ptype_id' in 'where clause'")
```

And finally some version numbers:

Django 1.4.5
Mysql Python 1.2.4

Any idea what I can do?